# Nucleo L476RG GPIO Switching behavior

Tags: stm32, embedded, st

In a Nucleo L476RG  with system/timers/peripherals CLK at 80MHz,
in the main loop I have code to directly access GPIOA register:

```
GPIOA->ODR = GPIO_ONE;
__NOP();
...
GPIOA->ODR = GPIO_ZERO;
```

The required pins have been configured for very fast speed:

```
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = { 0 };

        /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

        /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

        //
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
        ...
```

And the assembly generated looks fine:

```
 80010f4:       615a            str     r2, [r3, #20]
 80010f6:       bf00            nop
 80010f8:       bf00            nop
 80010fa:       bf00            nop
 80010fc:       bf00            nop
 80010fe:       6159            str     r1, [r3, #20]
 8001100:       bf00            nop
 8001102:       bf00            nop
 8001104:       bf00            nop
 8001106:       bf00            nop
 8001108:       615a            str     r2, [r3, #20]
 800110a:       bf00            nop
 800110c:       bf00            nop
 800110e:       bf00            nop
 8001110:       6159            str     r1, [r3, #20]
 8001112:       bf00            nop
 8001114:       bf00            nop
 8001116:       bf00            nop
 8001118:       615a            str     r2, [r3, #20]
 800111a:       bf00            nop
 800111c:       bf00            nop
 800111e:       6159            str     r1, [r3, #20]
 8001120:       bf00            nop
 8001122:       bf00            nop
 8001124:       e7e6            b.n     80010f4 <main+0x11c>
 8001126:       bf00            nop
```

However:

1. If the `str` fn is followed by none or a single `nop`, the pin does not toggle.
2. If the `str` fn is followed by 2 `nop`, the pin does toggle regularly, with a period of 40ns.
3. If the `str` fn is followed by a number of `nop` > 0, the pin toggle with a random period. In mean, it is the proper one, but clearly there are differences from one execution to the next one.
   In the attached picture, I captured how on an iteration of the loo where 3 and 2 pair of `nop` operations generate a different periods.
   In the next iteration, the pair of 2 `nop`s generate the desired wave.

I am directly loading the pin with the logic analyzer.
Thanks
[image]

What could be happening?

Comment: Anything running on background, like timer interrupts or DMA transfers? Is flash prefecth or other caches enabled?

Comment: Hi @Justme No, nothing in the background. I must say that the same behavior happens if I generate the patterns within an interruption handler (In the end, the whole idea was to generate a pattern every X miliseconds). When I saw this behavior, I stripped everything else and move the pattern generation to the main function

Comment: Your logic probe uses a too slow sampling rate. In its current configuration, it cannot measure such short pulses.

Comment: You are right, @codo, at 100MHz the width errors I see go down to 10ns. Thanks for pointing that out. Will repeat this once I get access to an scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment provided, if the MCU runs at 80MHz, the code is simply toggling the IO pin faster than what the logic analyzer sampling only at 25MHz can measure.